# How can I get query parameters token and the id in vue3

Tags: vue.js

How can I fetch query parameters in Vue.js?

`http://localhost:3000/rest-password?token=${token}&id=${data._id}

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the [JS API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup(){
    const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
    const token = params.get('token');
    const id = params.get('id');
  }
})
```

OR use [vueuse](https://vueuse.org/core/useurlsearchparams/?foo=bar&vueuse=awesome#useurlsearchparams)

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup(){
    const { token, id } = useUrlSearchParams('history')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get query parameters in Vue 3 Composition API (script setup) you can use **vue router** as follows:

**Option 1**: using `useRouter`:

```
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

const router = useRouter();

const queryParams = router.currentRoute.value.query
</script>
```

**Option 2**: using `useRoute`:

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute();

const queryParams = route.query
</script>
```